# Is there an example project in c++ that uses opencv and travis ci?

Tags: c++, opencv, github, cmake, travis-ci

I'm using Github as the source control tool, and I'd like to use the travis-ci plugin for CI. I didn't find any project that does that. Since travis-ci provides ubuntu 12.04 without the openCV libraries I'm installing those but then I'm having troubles using CMake to compile my code with the installed libraries.
I'd very much like to see an example project and it's .travis.yml if you know of one, preferably with a set-up that would work on both the travis ubuntu and windows for dev machines.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having with the CMake when you try to link to installed libs?

Comment: :) thanks for the response, it was 3 years ago, by now I have no clue what was that about...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a sample .travis.yml to build a project with CMake:

```
language: cpp

compiler:
  - gcc

before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake ..

script: make
```

The complete project is available from https://github.com/leutloff/diff-match-patch-cpp-stl. Another example is available from [Need hosted CI server with Qt4, sqlite3, cmake, git, gcc for project on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050329/).

Comment: you're right I deleted that post, thank you.
anyway if anyone is interested in a java and javaCV exmaple it's available [here](https://github.com/sagioto/LipReading)